# Where is the M2 SSD located in a HP 27-D1009NB series PC?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have an M2 SSD installed on my computer: An HP 27-D1009NB (Has a 1TB SSD 2.5 + 512GB M2).

However I can't seem to find it. I followed [this tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CA_7kIjg8Jc) but unfortunately it's not exactly the same model.

Here is a picture of the insides of my computer:

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: Find your specific users manual. Such drives are small. Mine (Lenovo) is buried under the removable drive bay.

Comment: Not user manual. *Service* manual. HP has em and they're very good

Comment: Incredible how much air they build into notebooks these days

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it - It is under the shield marked in red in the image below:

[image: ssd m2]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Its under the metal shield.